# If I'm encrypting a password before inserting into database, do I have to mysql_real_escape_string it?

Tags: php

I'm using sha1 to encrypt it. Should I mysql_real_escape_string() as well, or is encrypting it enough?

Comment: You should be using parametrized queries instead.

Comment: Those are two orthogonal concepts. Furthermore, sha1 is not an encryption algorithm

Comment: Depends on if you use the binary sha1 output, or hexencoded. -- But why wouldn't you escape it anyway? You picked the dated database interface that requires escaping values. Are you trying to evade the consequences of that cumbersome choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically speaking, the output from `sha1` will always be a hex-string, so you wouldn't need to escape it.

**However:** The answer to this question is always the same: escape the values. If it comes from a hard-coded variable 2 lines before your SQL, escape it. Always. Escape. Period. There are SO many other things to worry about optimizing.

Parameterized queries and PDO are always the best option, however

Second note: `sha1` and `md5` aren't the most secure for passwords. If you're not too far in, consider another solution such as blowfish

Comment: Escape then encrypt then, I assume?

Comment: @DougSmith There's no reason to escape before hashing. If you take my advice about always escaping, you would escape what _goes into_ your database (the already hashed value). Don't escape prior to hashing.

Comment: Yes escaping sounds like a good idea, after hashing. Simply because there could be another hack in play against the encryption function.